# How to split a list of different anagram words into separate lists in pure python?

Tags: python, string, list, split

I have this list of anagram words I'd like to split into nested lists if they have the same letters.

```
mylist = ["pots", "stop", "levi",  "vile", "evil", "spot", "star", "rats", "bingo", "live", "tops" "gobin"]
```

Result:

```
anagrams = [["pots", "stop", "spot", "tops"],
["levi", "live", "vile", "evil"],
["star", "rats"],
["bingo", "gobin"]]
```

I'd like to split them using pure python, i.e. not using any python packages such as groupby from itertools

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Can you please show your attempt and indicate specifically where you are stuck?

Comment: Hint: To tell if two strings are anagrams, use `sorted(s1) == sorted(s2)`

Comment: @MichaelRSF It isn't used as boolean, it actually creates a list based on characters sorted alphabetically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a dict with key as sorted word

```
mylist = ["pots", "stop", "levi",  "vile", "evil", "spot", "star", "rats", "bingo", "live", "tops", "gobin"]

res = {}

for i in mylist:
    res.setdefault(tuple(sorted(i)), []).append(i)

print(list(res.values()))
```

Output

```
[['pots', 'stop', 'spot', 'tops'], ['levi', 'vile', 'evil', 'live'], ['star', 'rats'], ['bingo', 'gobin']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list_of_strings = ['deltas', 'retainers', 'desalt', 'pants', 'slated', 'generating', 'ternaries', 'smelters', 'termless', 'salted', 'staled', 'greatening', 'lasted', 'resmelts']

def sort_anagrams(list_of_strings):
    new_list = []
    index = 0

    while len(list_of_strings) > 0:
        new_list.append([])
        new_list[index].append(list_of_strings[0])
        temp_compare = sorted(list_of_strings[0])
        for i in list_of_strings[1:]:
            if sorted(i) == temp_compare:
                new_list[index].append(i)
                list_of_strings.remove(i)
            else:
                continue
        list_of_strings.pop(0)
        index += 1
        
    print(new_list)
    return new_list
```